# Calculating probability values of a negative binomial distribution with mean and variance

Tags: negative-binomial-distribution

How can I calculate the probabilities of a negative binomial distribution given that I have the mean and variance (and also the set of random variables used) already available to me? I am looking to generate plots using these two parameters. Any python code or guidance on the approach would be hugely helpful.

Comment: This question is highly unclear. There seems to be a great deal of omitted context. Can you clarify what you mean by "the set of random variables used"? You started talking about *a* negative binomial, which suggests one random variable.  How many random variables are you talking about and how do they relate to the title question? What do you mean by "plots of these two parameters" -- if you have specified population parameters for one distribution, what is there to plot? A plot of mean vs variance would be a single point.  ... ctd

Comment: ctd ... When you talk about random variables being "used" it seems to suggest you're talking about *data*, not known population values, in which case you should be talking about *sample estimates* of mean and variance parameters, not the mean and variance. Please add enough context to resolve these issues and perhaps enough background that it's clear what underlying problem you're trying to solve (so we don't end up in an XY problem)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a negative binomial $\text{NB}(r,p)$ but you have the mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$, you can determine $r$ and $p$ via

$$
r = \frac{\sigma^2-\mu}{\sigma^2} \\
p = \frac{\mu^2}{\sigma^2 - \mu}
$$

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_binomial_distribution#Alternative_parameterizations

Hopefully that'll then allow you to calculate probabilities using some standard Python function.